# Avoid figure popping up continuously in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, popup, figure, axes

How can I avoid MATLAB from popping up a GUI figure `f` with two axes while plotting data inside a loop.
Here is a simple example:

```
f=figure;

ax.h1 = axes('Parent',f,'Position',[0.1 0.1 0.8 0.35],'Units','normalized');
ax.h2 = axes('Parent',f,'Position',[0.1 0.6 0.8 0.35],'Units','normalized');

for j=1:20
    axes(ax.h1)
    hold on
    plot(1:3,(1:3)+j)

    axes(ax.h2)
    hold on
    plot(1:3,(1:3)+1+j)

    pause(2)

end
```

I need to keep plotting data for several hours. So, it would be great if MATLAB didn´t pop up each time a new plot is generated.

Thanks!

Comment: Make the figure invisible... However, a much better approach would be to store the data, then plot everything in one go after it's ready.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe the reason you get them "popping up" is because you call the "axes" command, which has as a side effect that that particular axes will be displayed and brought to the forefront. If you just want to "plot" to that axes, you can do so directly from the `plot` command, i.e. `plot(ax.h1, bla bla bla`).

Comment: @Dev-iL. This is a GUI figure, with some buttons. So I want to keep looking to data. If I make the figure invisible my GUI will be invisible, and that cannot happen. If I keep storing data without ploting I cannot track what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TasosPapastylianou noted, the `axis` call is bringing the window to the front. Remove the `axis` and `hold on` calls within the loop and use `plot(ax.h1, ...` to plot to a specific axis. You only need to call `hold on` once for each axis, so do this at the start using `hold(ax.h1, 'on')` etc. Then your graphs should continue to update in the background without coming to the front each time.

Your example becomes:

```
f=figure;

ax.h1 = axes('Parent',f,'Position',[0.1 0.1 0.8 0.35],'Units','normalized');
ax.h2 = axes('Parent',f,'Position',[0.1 0.6 0.8 0.35],'Units','normalized');
hold(ax.h1, 'on')
hold(ax.h2, 'on')

for j=1:20
    plot(ax.h1, 1:3,(1:3)+j)
    plot(ax.h2, 1:3,(1:3)+1+j)

    pause(2)

end
```